# Jupyter Notebook display data frame in pandas "UNAUTHORIZED" Mac m1

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, unauthorized

I have been searching for a solution for a week now, to no avail.

our class is using Jupiter notebooks and we are provided with sheets and csv files for each lab. I have a Mac m1, and have used Anaconda for m1 GUI. I run Jupiter and it won't display data frame. I have changed the directories, used full path for file, created specific environments, tried every browser, no matter what, it will not display, I just get unauthorized. So last night I wiped my Mac, did a factory reset just incase I screwed up the directory permissions when I tried installing via terminal. Still get UNAUTHORIZED, and here is the real kicker... our school offers a web interface version if you don't want to instal, and it still does it! I am using clean downloaded files from my class which work on all the other students laptops.

I have attached a screenshot. I have made the file trusted. I have tried just df, df.head(), and a few other commands. nothing. Any help would be appreciated as my TA has blanked my emails.

[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKYDX.png)

Comment: That looks `df` may actually be giving you a dataframe in your screen capture. It isn't an error as I'd exepct. What if you execute `type(df)` after running what your screen capture shows. And also try executing `df.dtypes`. You show us the result with `df`. Then you say you tried "df.head(), and a few other commands. nothing. " What does 'nothing' mean? Describe what actually happens. Maybe replace 'nothing' with that in your post. Or at least what `df.head()` gives.

Comment: What do you see if you open 'data-majors.csv' in a code editor? The 'kicker' part with the web interface giving the same thing means it isn't your M1 mac though, right? Is your M1 Mac able to display other dataframes normally? (The Pandas documentation has ways to make them from code [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.to_dense.html).)